# how to get dynamically changed value of combobox into another textfield in the same jsp page

Tags: javascript, jsp

first.jsp
Here is my jsp page coding

```
Class: 
<select name="classn">
<option value="select">--Select--</option>
<option value="I class">I Class</option>
<option value="II class">II Class</option>
<option value="III class">III Class</option>
</select>
RollNO:
<input type="text" name="rollno" />
</body>
</html>
```

I want to get the classn value into text field

Answer (score 0):

From you question wording I understood that you want `select classn` value to `rollno text box`. Correct me if I am wrong.

Here is solution.
 **Javascript**

```
<script>
   function assingText()
    {
     var className = document.getElementById("classnId").value;
     if(className != "select")//check if it is not the select
     {
        document.getElementById("rollNoId").value = className;
     }
     else
     {
        document.getElementById("rollNoId").value = ""; //it clears the value if present
     }
    }  
</script>
```

Little change in your HTML code

```
Class: 
  <select name="classn" id="classnId" onchange="assingText()" > //here added id and onchange event is added
    <option value="select">--Select--</option>
    <option value="I class">I Class</option>
    <option value="II class">II Class</option>
    <option value="III class">III Class</option>
  </select>

RollNO:
  <input type="text" name="rollno" id="rollNoId"/> //here id is assigned to textbox
```